# RxJava recursive calling

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I found a very interesting case when you have to change initial `Observable` based on the data it has emitted.

I have `LocationManager`, that provides a location with a different interval between updates.

```
enum LocationUpdateFrequency {
    HEIGHT, MEDIUM, LOW
}

interface LocationManager {
    Observable<Location> getLocationUpdates(LocationUpdateFrequency frequency);

    LocationUpdateFrequency calcOptimalFrequency(Location currentLocation, Location prevLocation);
}
```

So I would like to subscribe to the initial getLocationUpdates with default value MEDIUM, and after it produces 2 location, I would like to resubscribe with new optimal frequency.

I have a solution, but it uses mutability:

```
class LocationState {
    Location currentLocation;
    Location pastLocation;

    boolean isValid() {
        return currentLocation != null && pastLocation != null;
    }
}

class LocationAndFrequency {
    final Location location;
    final LocationUpdateFrequency frequency;

    public LocationAndFrequency(Location location, LocationUpdateFrequency frequency) {
        this.location = location;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }
}

public Observable<Location> getOptimalLocationUpdates() {
    final LocationManager locationManager = null;
    final LocationState state = new LocationState();
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
                final LocationUpdateFrequency frequency;
                if (state.isValid()) {
                    frequency = locationManager.calcOptimalFrequency(state.currentLocation, state.pastLocation);
                } else {
                    frequency = LocationUpdateFrequency.MEDIUM;
                }

                return locationManager.getLocationUpdates(frequency)
                        .doOnNext(location -> {
                            state.pastLocation = state.currentLocation;
                            state.currentLocation = location;
                        })
                        .map(location -> new LocationAndFrequency(location, frequency));
            })
            .takeUntil(locationAndFrequency -> {
                final LocationUpdateFrequency optimalFrequency =
                        locationManager.calcOptimalFrequency(state.currentLocation, state.pastLocation);
                return locationAndFrequency.frequency != optimalFrequency;
            })
            .map(locationAndFrequency -> locationAndFrequency.location)
            .repeat();
}
```

What is more elegant solution?

Comment: does getLocationUpdates onComplete after on value or is it infinit, pushing values as they arrive? It looks like it would only produce on value, because of repeat.

Comment: no, it is infinitive, I use takeUntil and repeat together: the idea is to be subscribed as long as selected `getLocationUpdates` is optimal and after that takeUntil will unsubscribe and repeat would subscribe to new optimal. I would like to achieve the same behavior, without having mutability.

Comment: Could you have a look at this impl? I am using a Subject, but this could also change: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a2b757c55135ec88a9f5c1b3836badac

Comment: Great job, very nice example, how to implement it using subject. Just curious is it possible to implement without subject, and mutable variables?

Comment: Well, I think the trick is to subscribe to the stream and always replay the last value on subscription. It is a mechanisem like the subject. You may have a look at another example of mine: https://gitlab.com/HansWurst315/RxJavaExamples . Later I will change the implementation to not use subjects and post it as an answer.